# Why is swift's JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:) taking 10-15 seconds for just 1mb data?

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, jsondecoder

I'm using swift's JSONDecoder to decode a JSON data of about 1mb. My JSON has a bunch of nested objects.
I'm decoding using init(from decoder:) to decode my JSON data. The issue is that it takes about 10-15 seconds to decode the JSON only after the API call returns with a success response. Why is this happening(the size of my data is not that large)?
Also, how can I reduce this time?

I'm testing on an iPhone 6 and on the Xcode simulator.
The API call takes about 1-2 seconds to get the JSON.

I'm using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) here's a sample of my api call:

```
API.provider.request(API.getDetails(id: courseID), completion:  { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            do {
                var results = try JSONDecoder().decode(MiniDetailApiResponse.self, from: response.data)
                delegate?.success(results)
              }catch{
                 delegate?.failure()
              }
}
```

Comment: show code  or api that you are hitting >?

Comment: Yes this question is hopeless to answer without the relevant code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've edited my question description and added a sample of my API call. I cannot share the actual code structure but I hope this helps.

Comment: @jawadAli I've edited the description please have a look. 
P.S. Ignore that switch is not exhaustive. It's just a sample.

Comment: Since the API call isn't a problem this isn't very helpful. Maybe you could add some print statements with timestamps in your structs to try to figure out what part is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding from JSON probably isn't taking that long, unless you're doing something very interesting in custom `init(from: Decoder)`, but you haven't included anything from `MinDetailApiResponse` in your question so it's hard to tell.

If your 10-15 seconds figure is derived from you waiting for something to change on the screen, then the most likely cause is that the API request call above isn't being called on the main thread, which often reveals itself as a long delay to UI updates.

Put a breakpoint on `var results = try...` above, and when it gets hit, look in the debug navigator - are you on the main thread?

[image]

If not, you should call your delegate method on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { delegate?.success(results) }
```